# Python mechanicalsoup get web form

Tags: python, forms, request, python-requests

I am writing a *standalone bot* that log into [JitJat](https://jitjat.org/login.php), an anonymous instant messaging site and send a message to a user. I successfully do this and I reach [the index](https://jitjat.org/index.php) where I select my recipient.

Finally, I can chat with somebody at [the chat](https://jitjat.org/chat.php) but whenever I try to get the *form* of the page I get *None*.
I tried to do this many times, using robobrowser, requests and mechanicalsoup.

Here my script:

```py
import mechanicalsoup

#Current url: https://jitjat.org/login.php
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open('https://jitjat.org/login.php')
print('Current url: ' + str(browser.get_url()))
browser.select_form()
browser['username'] = 'my username'
browser['password'] = 'my password'
browser.submit_selected()
print('Redirect: ' + str(browser.get_url()))

#Current url: https://jitjat.org/index.php
browser.follow_link("recipient username")
print('Redirect: ' + str(browser.get_url()))

#Current url: https://jitjat.org/chat.php?id=(recipient username)
browser.select_form()
print(browser.get_current_form().print_summary())
```

Here the page source:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

 <title>JitJat - anonymous instant messaging</title>
    
    <link href="css/jChat.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" />
 
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/user_css.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" />
   
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jChat.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    
</head>

<body>
 
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
        
           <div id="header">  
                <div id="logo">
                    <a href="index.php"><h1>logo</h1></a>
                </div>
    
                <div id="info">
                    <ul id="userBox">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">ni47gv2x9ne<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="?action=logout&token=20419ec4554207718f71e9c5255f3514"><span class="icon-off"></span> <strong>Logout</strong></a></li>
                            </ul>
                       </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a><span class="divider">&raquo;</span></li>
            <li class="active">Chat</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    



    
        <div class="container">
        <ul class="breadcrumb" align="center">
            <li><noscript>
<span style="font-weight: normal; color: #ff0000">You need to have scripting enabled to use Chat.</span>
</noscript>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('You are using <span style="font-weight: bold">Chat</span>.');
</script> Click to enter <a href="/chat.php?id=Bluebear&mode=messaging"><span style="font-weight: normal">Messaging</span></a> <img src="images/ui/question.png" width="13" height="13" style="vertical-align: -1px;" title="differences: click-to-send, manual refresh, manual scroll, multiple lines possible, delete single messages, see if message is unread"></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
    
 <!-- BOX -->
    <div class="box">
    
     <div class="header">
     
        <div style="z-index: 10; position: absolute; left: 88%; margin-top: 8px; width: 135px; height: 25px; border: 0px solid black;"><a href="/chat.php?id=Bluebear&nuke=1&mode=" title="delete all messages permanently">nuke conversation</a></div>

        <h4><img src="images/avatars/user1.png" width="14" height="14" style="vertical-align: -2px;"> <a href="/chat.php?id=bluebear&mode=">bluebear</a></h4>

        
        </div>

        
        
    
                <div class="content">
   <!-- jChat -->
            <ul class="messages-layout">
                <li class="messages"></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Enter message field -->
             <span class="session_time">Online</span><span id="sample"></span>
            <div class="message-entry">
                <input type="text" id="text-input-field" class="input-sm" name="message-entry" /> 
                <div class="send-group">
                    <a href="#emoticons" data-option="emotions" class="attachEmotions" data-toggle="modal"></a>
                    <input type="submit" name="send-message" id="sendMessage" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send" />
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Emoticons Modal -->
            <div id="emoticons" class="modal hide fade">
                <div class="modal-header"><h4>Emotions</h4></div>
                <div class="modal-body"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <!-- // jChat -->
                     
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <!-- // END BOX -->
    
    
    
    
     
    </div>
                  
</body> 
   
   <script>
     $().Chat();
   </script>
   
</html>
```

How can I fix it? Do you have any idea to solve it??

Thank you for the attention!

Comment: Hmm, if the page source that you posted is the one in which you're looking for the form, it would make sense that you're obtaining `None`, since it doesn't appear to have a form tag. Perhaps you meant to post the source for the page once you've logged in? Or, perhaps this is the correct source and accessing via form is not the correct way to interface with the chat?

Comment: Thank you so much for attention! You were very quick! The source code is correct. If there isn't any form, how can I interact with the page?

Comment: The `select_form` function of `mechanical_soup` will only work if there is a form on the page. That is, something within an HTML `<form>` tag. Looking at the source, that appears to be absent. Since the chat application appears to be interacting with Javascript, I would search on what Python libraries exist that would help in directly interfacing with Javascript web code. Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Thank you for the help! Sorry to have bothered you.

Comment: Please, it's no bother at all. That's precisely the purpose of StackOverflow, and I'm happy to help where I can. Best of luck with your project, and cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue.
For all those who have problems similar to this, due to particular html codes, I recommend using **robobrowser**, a smart cross-platform module
(useful documentation [here](https://robobrowser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html)).

If for some reason you can not get the form of the page:

1. Try to specify the id of the form, like:

   `browser = RoboBrowser(id='FormId')`
2. Try to pass headers with requests module:

   `import requests
   mysession = requests.session()
   open = mysession.get('website_url')
   print(open.headers)`

   Add headers like so:

   `mysession.headers = open.headers
   browser = RoboBrowser(id='FormId', session=mysession, history=True)`

Hope it helps!